# _sas_ Empty sheet created while using proc export in sas

Tags: sas, data-analysis

*sas* Empty sheet is created while using proc export in sas. why does this get created and how to avoid this?

```
proc export data=temp
outfile="//../../test.xlsx"
dbms=excelcs
replace;
sheet="Output"
port=****;
server="***.com";serveruser="****";serverpass="****";
run;
```